Custom engine in material output target
I have copied the source code of Cycles engine (which is just an addon)
https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/src/branch/main/intern/cycles/blender/addon
renamed it to "Mask" (and all functions variables were renamed accordingly) and made by own engine which works just fine. I can set Render Engine to Mask in the settigns and I can render the image properly.
Unfortunately my engine does not show up among targets in the Material Output node

Could somebody point me to the functions responsible for registering my engine in such a way that it will show up in Material Output target?
